# doctrine create query with 2 association

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

i have this entity

Post

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SottoCategoria")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sottocategoria_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
public $sottocategoria;
```

SottoCategoria

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categoria")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoria_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
public $categoria;
```

Categoria

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SottoCategoria", mappedBy="categoria")
 */
protected $sottocategorie;
```

how can I make this query? i need to find all post from categoria

post.sottocategoria.categoria

```
 $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->where('p.enabled = :enabled AND p.sottocategoria.categoria = :categoria')
                    ->setParameters(array(
                        'enabled' => true,
                        'categoria' => $idCat,
                    ))
```

i can't use p.categoria because i not have relation with post

my relation is  post  ->  sottocategoria -> categoria
so my question is how i get all post from categoria? i have to use innerjoin?

Answer (score 0):

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $query = $em->createQuery(
                            'SELECT p,g,c FROM AcmeBlogBundle:Post p JOIN p.sottocategoria g JOIN g.categoria c WHERE p.enabled = :enabled AND g.categoria = :categoria ORDER BY p.id DESC')

solved